# Выбор строк содержащих данные другой строки

Tags: mysql, sas

подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем именно ошибка

Есть два столбца, в которых строки одного столбца могут содержать значения другого, например:

- Доходы от повременной платы - prepaid (ст.1) и   Доходы от повременной платы (ст.2)
- или (EX) Бизнес: Доходы от услуг (ст.1) и (EX) Доходы от услуг (ст.2).

Я задаю формулу, которая должна третьему столбцу присвоить значение второго столбца, если тот содержится в первом.

Код вот такой:

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE WORK.SPS1_1111 AS 
SELECT t1.'Наименование счета'n, 
      t1.'Наименование счета (агрегат)'n, 
/* Вычисление */
        case
when t1.'Наименование счета'n contains t1.'Наименование счета (агрегат)'n
Then t1.'Наименование счета (агрегат)'n
Else ' '
        end
AS 'Вычисление'n
  FROM WORK.SPS1_0000 t1;
QUIT;
```

Но в результате у меня выдает только нулевые значения там, где должна была сработать формула.

При этом если есть полное совпадение между строк, то он выдает значение.

Comment: А вы не могли бы показать пример данных , на которых исполняете код? Вот пример кода,кторый ищет совпадение по вашем условиею в стандартном датасете : `data res;
 set sashelp.class;

 if find(UPCASE(Name),SEX) then
  do;
   bool=1;
  end;
run;`

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте наличие лишних пробелов в конце строки.
Если проблема в этом, то убрать их можно командой strip

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE WORK.SPS1_1111 AS 
SELECT t1.'Наименование счета'n, 
      t1.'Наименование счета (агрегат)'n, 
/* Вычисление */
        case
when t1.'Наименование счета'n contains strip(t1.'Наименование счета (агрегат)'n)
Then t1.'Наименование счета (агрегат)'n
Else ' '
        end
AS 'Вычисление'n
  FROM WORK.SPS1_0000 t1;
QUIT;
```